# Approximation for integral of Matrix Exponential

Tags: integration, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I am trying to implement some algorithm in matlab. To this end, I need to discretise a system of differential equation as $\dot x = A x + B u$.

Starting with initial condition $x_0$ the system after a single time step $h$ will reach
$$
x(h) = e^{Ah}x_0 + \int_0^h e^{A(h-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau.
$$

Assuming $u(\tau)$ to be constant in $[0,h]$, the previous expresion reduces to
$$
x(h) = e^{Ah}x_0 + \left (\int_0^h e^{As}ds\right ) Bu,
$$
with $s =h-\tau$.

The first exponential matrix $e^{Ah}$ is calculated with matlab command

> expm(A*h).

As far as I know, there is no command which approximate the term $\int_0^h e^{As}ds$ so I thought to use the expansion series to approximate it as

$$
\int_0^h e^{As}ds = \int_0^h I + As + \frac{1}{2}A^2 s^2 + \cdots ds \\
= Ih + \frac{1}{2}Ah^2 + \frac{1}{6}A^2 h^3 + \cdots 
$$

I evaluate this expression in matlab up to some degree. The method works right but I'd like to ask you if there is a better approximation to it (maybe padé?).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential According to wikipedia and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, matrix exponential is expressible as a polynomial of degree $n$, where $n$ is dimension of matrix.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible you can evaluate that integral with the same technique you would use for the scalar case. You can also evaluate that integral numerically (dividing $[0,h]$ into small intervals etc. )

Comment: This integral is the expression of a solution of a system of differential equations. Why not use a numerical method to solve this system, without resorting to this integral? (for example, using a Runge-Kutta method or any other that suits your needs)

Comment: Another idea, since you are using Matlab: slide 12 of [this slideshow](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/exp10.pdf) by Nicholas Higham has the same equation, and suggests looking at the functions [c2d](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html) and [d2c](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/d2c.html) of the Control System Toolbox. You may also have a look at *[19 dubious ways...](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf)* by Moler & Van Loan (this is the updated version of the document published in 2003, not the originial published in 1978).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try using a system with c2d, hoping it won't take too long. The point of doing this scripting is that I need the system to evolve for a number of steps, then taking some action and maybe changing the matrices describing the system. As this is done quite intensively, I didn't want to make any function call in the main loop but just calculating the new state by matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user287773 A little bit off topic, but if the linear transformations are in some way reducible to a $4 \times 4$, directxmath library in c++ or openGL libraries may improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy way to compute $\Phi(h)=\int_0^h e^{As}Bds$.

To this aim, define the matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and compute $e^{Mh}$, which is given by

$$e^{Mh}=\begin{bmatrix}e^{Ah} & \Phi(h)\\0 & I\end{bmatrix}.$$

This can be proven using the power series definition of the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

This is **EXACTLY** from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

"If $P$ and $Q_t$ are nonzero polynomials in one variable, such that $P(A)=0$, and if the memorphic function

$f(z)=\frac{e^{tz}-Q_t(z)}{P(z)}$

is entire, then $e^{tA}=Q_t(A)$"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless that's not helping me.
I'm not looking for an exact solution but an approximation for a step size small enough.

Further, maybe it was not clear from above, I have no knowledge about the matrix $A$.

I need a procedure which given an input matrix $A$ it gives as output an approximation of the integral of the exponential matrix.

By now I'm using a power series expansion aborted at some point but maybe there is another solution which I am not aware of.

Comment: You could use a Pade-approximation for the power series of the integral. This is not necessarily more precise, in the sense of error order, but maintains the quality of the error for a larger  range of $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer of *marshal craft*, for the integral you might want to chose $Q_t$ such that
$$
P(z)|\left(\frac{e^{tz}-1}z-Q_t(z)\right)
$$